# meaning of "is turning a page"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Although US forces continue to target terrorists in the region and remain deployed at bases throughout the Middle East, Biden suggested he **was turning a page** after the US invasions of Iraq and Afghanistan.

[article link](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2022/jul/16/joe-biden-arab-leaders-summit)

Q: If "turn a page" a momentary verb, is it wrong to have progressive tense? And What does it mean, he finished sth or he would do sth?

Comment: It means **moving ahead** (probably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not wrong, it is the usual progressive sense of "an action currently in progress".  In the literal meaning "turn a page" is quite quick, but it still isn't *instant*.

But this is a metaphor, meaning "changing policy, and moving to a new type of relationship" and this might take weeks or months (or more).  There's nothing odd about using the progressive. It means neither "finished" or "would do". It means "currently in progress".